# Voice recognition in background

Tags: android, android-service

The app I am currently working on is basicly just a service that runs in the background.

What I am trying to archieve is that whenever you say a keyword it has to perform that operation. The user is fully aware of this running in the background.

The only problem I have is that I can't seem to figure out how to run a voice recognition in the background. Any ideas how I can archieve this? It can also be a voice to text running in the background that doesn't matter too much.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer is no..activity would have to have focus to work and that means not in background..

Comment: Any ideas how I can do this with a minimal UI? Where you don't have to constantly click on a button?